# Receiving array in route data to be used in Where func + MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am receiving an array in route data containing different string values. Since I don't know how many string values I am going to receive, I cant have a definite **Where** function. Hence I am looping through the array and making multiple calls to DB set, fetching the result and adding it into another Master List. Please see code below.

```
public JsonResult GetModels(string brand)
{
    string[] brands = brand.Split(seperator);
    MasterList.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < brands.Length; i++)
    {
        tempString = brands[i];
        tempList = db.Devices.Where(r => r.Brand.Equals(tempString)).Select(r => new MySelectList { Value = r.PhoneModel, Text = r.PhoneModel }).Distinct().ToList();

        for (int a = 0; a < tempList.Count; a++)
            MasterList.Add(tempList[a]);
    }
    return Json(MasterList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Is there a way I can somehow avoid looping through the array and use it directly in Where function? Meaning **Where** function can look into values of the array and return result based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx). This effectively generates an SQL `IN` clause:

```
tempList = db.Devices.Where(r => brands.Contains(r.Brand));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't realize it was that easy :)